# Xml parser - How can I get such a link?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am using an XML parser to parse through and XML response. I need to get all the links in the XML page that I'm parsing, and those are showed in this form:

```
<src url="link"> Link Name </src>
```

How can I get the "link"? I only know how to get the "Link Name" using

```
if(name.equals("url"))
    text = parser.getNextText();
```

Thank you for helping!

This is my code:

```
try 
    {       
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();  
        XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();  
        parser.setInput( new StringReader( response ) );
        int k=0;
        int event;
          while (true) {  

              event = parser.next();  

              if (event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                  {  
                   String name = parser.getName();  

                      String text = null;  
                      while (true) {                             

                          if (name.equals("t")) 
                              {                                   

                                  text = parser.nextText();
                                  title.setText(text);

                              }
                                  else 
                                    if(name.equals("jt"))
                                    {
                                    text = parser.nextText();    
                                    if(!text.equals(""))
                                    adapter.add(text);
                                    }   
                                     else 
                                        if(name.equals("src"))
                                        {
                                        text = parser.(); 
                                        System.out.println(text);
                                        if(!text.equals(""))                                            
                                        link.add(text);
                                        }

                          event = parser.next();
                          if (event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {  
                              name = parser.getName(); 
                              if (name.equals("shrs"))  
                                  break;

                          } 
                          else break;
                          }


                      }  

               else if (event == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && parser.getName().equals("shrs"))  
                 break;
```

Comment: You'll need to supply us with a bit more info here.  Best would be a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you search something like this?

```
    int countAtr= text.getAttributeCount();
    if(countAtr > 0) {
        attrs = new HashMap<String,String>(acount);
        for(int i=0;x<countAtr;x++) {
            attrs.put(parser.getAttributeName(x), parser.getAttributeValue(x));
        }
    }
```

Comment: @AnTz that crosses the line between asking for educational help and asking someone to do your work for you, and is really inappropriate for stackoverflow.